# Surely it's just scenery

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual, music

Surely it's just scenery... EDIT: tag added, hopefully this remains non-trivial.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> not your username, but your **profile picture!** - that is, Rick Astley in **Never Gonna Give You Up**!

Look carefully at

> the black dots in the scenery. These are the notes played in the chorus of Never Gonna Give You Up. You can listen to that part of the song [here](https://youtu.be/dQw4w9WgXcQ?si=bDmRutO6QLeFf-w_&t=85), or compare with a music sheet I found on the internet (with some scribbles to match the scenery):

> [image: music sheet]